# Check ros2 node status

Tags: ros2, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using ROS1, I am able to use ros::master::getNodes to check the nodes that is functioning through code usage.

I wonder to know is there any way that ros2 can achieve the same functionality which is to get the functioning nodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378825/check-ros2-node-status/) by [enyuin](https://answers.ros.org/users/74920/enyuin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2021-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rclpy.Node.get_node_names() solves the problem!!

---

Originally posted by [enyuin](https://answers.ros.org/users/74920/enyuin/) with karma: 45 on 2021-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2